# How do I write consecutive times to a text file without listing all times, only the final range?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, datetime, txt

I am currently writing datetimes to a txt file. It currently looks like this:

```
2021-01-01 06:52:00 ,
2021-01-01 06:54:00 ,
2021-01-01 06:55:00 ,
2021-01-01 06:56:00 ,
2021-01-01 06:57:00 ,
2021-01-01 06:59:00 ,
2021-01-01 07:01:00 ,
```

I would instead like it to be displayed as a list of start and end times, like this:

```
2021-01-01 06:52:00 , 2021-01-01 06:52:00
2021-01-01 06:54:00 , 2021-01-01 06:59:00
2021-01-01 07:01:00 , 2021-01-01 07:01:00
```

You can see that any time there are consecutive times, it shows the range (2021-01-01 06:54:00 , 2021-01-01 06:59:00), and any time there is not a consecutive time, it repeats the time in the "end time" column.

My code currently looks like this, where time_values is just a numpy array of times from an xarray file:

```
        time_list_array = []
        for t in time_values:
            start_time = pd.to_datetime(str(t)).strftime(
                '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            time_list_array.append(start_time)

        #Write list of datetimes to txt file
        full_path = '/home/'
        if path.exists(full_path) is False:
            mkdir(full_path)
        with open(full_path+'.txt', 'a') as text_file:
            for t in time_list_array:
                text_file.write('%s ,\n' % t)
```

Comment: The first and last line of your desired output only show duplicates of the first and last entry of the input. Why's that? And what's the relation to numpy?

Comment: The initial list of times is a list of all instances where temperature exceeds 60 degrees F. The data only collects every minute, so any time there are consecutive times, I'd rather just show a range (like the middle line of my desired output). We still want to list single, lone times where the temp exceeds 60F however, but a start and end time is needed. So, repeating the time as the start and end date is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement in `for t in time_list_array:` includes `'\n'`. This creates a new line every time. You want to write 2 time values on the same line THEN add `'\n'` at the end. You need a small modification to the loop and the write format. Something like this:

```
for i in range(len(time_list_array)//2):
    text_file.write(f'{time_list_array[2*i]} , {time_list_array[2*i+1]}\n')
```

Note: this assumes you have an even number of entries in time_list_array.

This is another way to solve the problem, using `Odd` to track which format to use.

```
with open('test_2.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    Odd = True
    for t in time_list_array:
        if Odd:
            text_file.write(f'{t}')
        else:
            text_file.write(f' , {t}\n')
        Odd = not(Odd)
```